# Cannot get the current row value of column "[MSDASQL].LONG_DESCRIPTION" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server :--NETSUITE

Tags: sql, sql-server, netsuite, sql-server-2016

I am trying to get fetch data into sql server 2016 from ITEM_SITE_CATEGORIES table in Netsuite. 
I am running following query:

```
select * from  OPENQUERY (LINKEDSRVR,'select LONG_DESCRIPTION FROM ITEM_SITE_CATEGORIES');
```

it is throwing error

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "NETSUITE" returned message "Requested conversion is not supported.".
Msg 7341, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the current row value of column "[MSDASQL].LONG_DESCRIPTION" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "NETSUITE".
```

All Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: which database you are trying to information from ? select long_description from dbname.schemaname.tablename

Comment: DB: SQL server 2016;   select long_description from dbname.schemaname.tablename this is also returning same error.

Comment: Did  u Checked the configurations on Linked server permissions or properties, or are you able to access any tables from that linked server ?

Comment: Yes i can able to access other column of that table; that value of 'LONG_DESCRIPTION' column is too long; seems more than 8000 characters.

Comment: Can you try this query if this works and we can work from there, select LONG_DESCRIPTION into #temp  FROM  linkedserver.db.schema.table

Answer (score 4):

Try casting your column (and check the length):

```
select * from  OPENQUERY (LINKEDSRVR,'
select
    CAST(LONG_DESCRIPTION AS CHAR(8000)) AS LONG_DESCRIPTION
    ,LENGTH(LONG_DESCRIPTION) AS LD_LEN
FROM ITEM_SITE_CATEGORIES');
```

If exists LD_LEN = 8000 then you are going to lose some data.

Comment: thanks working for clodera impala connection as well